# How do I call a dialog component from an OpenSocial gadget in IBM Connections?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'd like to use an OpenSocial gadget within the "My Page" screen to display a [Grid](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/tableGrid.htm) of results.

Clicking on a link in the grid would popup either a [Dialog](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/dialog.htm) (like for the "Share" button) or a Flyout (like for embedded experiences in the activity stream).

How would I achieve this? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David there is an example of how to do this in the developer bootstrap page in Connections.  You should be able to call [gadgets.views.openGadget](http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/spec/trunk/Core-Gadget.xml#gadgets.views.openGadget) API to open a dialog.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, 

For the record, the relevant gadget can be located at e.g.:
http://connections4.example.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.gadget/test/container/gadgets/bootstrap_views.xml

Requiring the following:
<Require feature="views"></Require>
<Require feature="open-views.gadget"></Require>

Comment: *See:* https://greenhouse.lotus.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.gadget/test/container/gadgets/bootstrap_views.xml for a complete gadget ;)

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ryan's point, you can see some info on using the bootstrap page on [developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/osgadgetconnections4/index.html), you'll want to look at the views example gadget. Unfortunately you can only open a dialog in Connections, the EE style flyout is not available to gadgets on My Page.

Comment: Thanks David, having access to Dialog only seems entirely appropriate - Flyout would not work well for gadgets in the right hand column.